# Grease Pencil Masks - Partial Transparency

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, masking

I'm attempting to recreate this mask transparency effect I did in Procreate where it's not a perfect mask, and you can still somewhat see the masked object through the mask (pictured below).

[image: procreate "partial transparency mask" example]

Notice how you can still see the paper background texture inside the shape that masks the line. I want to give it the feeling of erasing the pencil stroke on the paper, but the stroke is still somewhat there since erasers on paper are not perfect.

I'm new to Grease Pencil, and I've managed to figure out how to get masks to work in general, but it's a TOTAL mask and not a partially transparent one. The closest attempt I've gotten is to have the mask shape be white with 0.7 alpha and "regular" blend mode on the layer, which does make the masked line somewhat visible like I wanted, but you can't see the paper background due to the white fill on the mask.

[image: attempted blender recreation #1]

On the opposite end of the spectrum, using black as the color for the mask shape, 1.0 opacity, using "add" blend mode, this will allow the paper background to go through, but also completely mask the object (which is also not what I want).

[image: attempted blender recreation #2]

Is there any way I can achieve the effect from Procreate in Blender Grease Pencil?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be more of a grease pencil material issue than a layers or a masking problem. Because the desired color of your stroke *(opacity of your shape over your stroke)* is inconsistent with the desired color of your fill area *(opacity of your shape over your background)*, we have no choice but to separate these two into two different materials to achieve your desired result.

First, after drawing the enclosed *transparent shape* within your own *"Lines"* layer, duplicate it into a new layer with a new assigned material *(*<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> *to duplicate and* <kbd>M</kbd> *to move to new layer)*. For example, I duplicated the enclosed shape into a layer I named, *Color*. The new material to be assigned would be identical to the stroke material but with a fill. Since we will use this material to change the color of the original stroke, I placed my *Color* layer over the lines and made the *"Lines"* layer into its mask.

[image]

I duplicated the enclosed *transparent shape* again with a separate *"Solid Fill"* material *(also into a separate "Fills" layer for organization)* since this material will be used to view the background.

[image]

Now that we made the material to view the background different from the material that changes the color of the stroke, it doesn't matter how much black, white, or transparency we use to change the contrast. Although you used the built-in opacity of the layers, I changed the opacity with *Opacity modifiers* for the materials.

[image]

The result upon rendering with a background should be your desired effect.

[image]

Additionally, even though I didn't show it, I combined all the *transparent shapes* and its duplicates across the different layers into a single *Vertex Group* for easy editing and transformation.